# Why do I get an autolayout error on a constraint that should not be installed for the size class?

Tags: ios

I'm using iOS 8. My nib has autolayout and size classes enabled. I've made two layouts in IB, one for Any Width/Any Height, and one for Any Width/Compact Height. I've tested different orientations and device sizes in IB and I don't have constraint problems in IB.

Now when I run the app on my phone. The view lays out correctly in portrait. Then I rotate my phone into landscape and I get a "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." error. When I look at the list of conflicting constraints, I see a constraint that should have been uninstalled for landscape layouts. When rotation completes the landscape layout appears correctly.

It's as if iOS is trying to lay out the view with the new bounds before the old constraints are uninstalled. Is this a known problem with iOS? Is there a step I need to implement to correctly support size classes?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem! When I rotate to portrait (on the simulator) I get a conflicting constraint on an constraint that is *not* installed for that size class! Maddening! I keep resetting the constraints -- same error!

Comment: A bug IMHO, some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968564/3046504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think this is an iOS bug, but I don't have time to make a sample project to reproduce it. I think what is unusual about this layout is that I have an image view that moves to an entirely different location when the phone is rotated into landscape.

The width constraint on the image view had different constants for either size class, but this was throwing an exception.

The next thing tried was to use different width constraints. One was installed for compact height, the other was installed for everything else. This was still throwing an exception, even though the breaking constraint should not have been installed.

Finally, the solution I got working was to have two image views, one for regular layouts, and one for compact height. Only one image view was installed at a time. This works without exceptions and looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same issue. Very frustrating! At first I added code to willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator: in order to detect if the newCollection was a size class that didn't need the constraint. If so, then I set the constraint.active = NO.

It did the trick, but I hated the code.  I was just like, "Why should I have to do this?  The constraint is not installed for the new size class!"

Then I figured out that if I lowered the priority of the offending constraint to 999 in interface builder I no longer got the constraint error in the console when I rotated.  :-)  And all is right with the world again.

Comment: I'm currently 'enjoying' this problem too - and I think I'll be giving your priority trick a go.  But do you know if constraint conflicts of this nature could ever cause a crash / similar problem and whether Apple would reject an app purely on this basis?

Comment: Tried it - it worked.  You're a Duchess.  Have an up vote.