# iOS 8 autolayout constraint messed up in different size classes

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout

I have a view named 'vertical 1' in my universal app (iOS 8), in iPad(wAny hAny), its height is 238, and in iPhone portrait(wCompact, hRegular), its height is dynamically caculated by its top and bottom view. The code segament in xib file like below, note that constraint (id: `05F-Ed-Vem`) is exclued in `heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact` variation. All constaints have no problem in Interface Builder.

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" misplaced="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="BjW-gW-lfX" userLabel="vertical 1">
    <rect key="frame" x="501" y="20" width="1" height="238"/>
    <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="groupTableViewBackgroundColor"/>
    <constraints>
        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="238" id="05F-Ed-Vem"/>
        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="1" id="ETL-HL-PI1"/>
        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="1" id="iNR-DD-mpQ"/>
    </constraints>
    <variation key="default">
        <mask key="constraints">
            <exclude reference="ETL-HL-PI1"/>
        </mask>
    </variation>
    <variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact">
        <mask key="constraints">
            <exclude reference="05F-Ed-Vem"/>
            <include reference="ETL-HL-PI1"/>
            <exclude reference="iNR-DD-mpQ"/>
        </mask>
    </variation>
</view>
```

But when I run app in iPhone 5s simulator which is wCompact hRegular size, I got console warning like below

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa6327ca1f0 V:[UIView:0x7fa6327c9e70(238)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa6327d1510 V:[UIView:0x7fa6327d2ca0(250)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa6327dcea0 V:[UIView:0x7fa6327d2ca0]-(16)-[UIView:0x7fa6327dc2e0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa6327dddf0 V:[UIView:0x7fa6327c9e70]-(19)-[UIView:0x7fa6327dc2e0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa6327dc760 V:[UIView:0x7fa6327cbb60]-(8)-[UIView:0x7fa6327d2ca0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa6327dea90 V:[UIView:0x7fa6327cbb60]-(15)-[UIView:0x7fa6327c9e70]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa6327d1510 V:[UIView:0x7fa6327d2ca0(250)]>
```

which is very very weird, because height 238 should not be presented in iPhone layout right? Does anyone know why? Thank you in advance.

Update:
I have tried to clear all my constraints in wCompact, hRegular size (in the other word, no **ANY** constraints in this size), still got `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` warning in iPhone simulator. And those constraints in wAny, hAny work perfectly in iPad.

Found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023201/why-do-i-get-an-autolayout-error-on-a-constraint-that-should-not-be-installed-fo) which has a similar problem.

Update:
I found the problem **ONLY** exists in custom `UITableViewCell`, even only has two simple `UIImageView` and `UIView`, contraints defined in wAny hAny and uninstalled in wCompact hRegular will be presented in iPhone simulator, and the warning occurs.

Comment: when you change the size classes , make sure to clear the constraints and then again put the constraints

Comment: Compact width / regular height is EXACTLY `"For all iPhones in portrait"`. You even state "which is wCompact hRegular size" - exactly the size class that is specified in the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally I use two separated `xib` files, one for phone, one for pad.

At least it works.

:(