# IOS AutoLayout with constraint exception when switching between landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have different size classes for iPhone 6+ landscape and portrait. I don't get any constraint error if i run starting from landscape or portrait. The moment i switch from landscape or portrait, i get constraint errors. It seems that if i switch i get a merge of both portrait and landscape's size classes constraint. I have only set up for 1. Regular Width and Compact Height 2. Any Width and Compact Height 3. Compact Height and Regular Width 4. Regular Width and Regular Height. Did i do something wrong that could cause a conflict. Thanks.

Comment: when you go in landscape from portrait or vice versa remove first old constraints before adding new ones.

Comment: Do you have any sample code on how to remove the old constraints? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add constraints for the `Any` size class then they will apply in all orientations on all devices so you need to ensure that they are compatible with all other constraints. Based on the combinations you've specified (there looks to be a typo in your list) it seems like you may have over engineered but it's hard to be sure. Look first at the constraint that's removed by the layout engine and where it's defined then you can find out what the clash is with and turn that one off in some size classes or rework your size classes so that they're all separate or use the `Any` case more consistently.

Comment: I was planning to show different layout for different orientation. If i don't switch orientation then there is no error. It's only when i switch. Which size classes should i change my layout to support different layout for different orientation. Thanks.

Comment: Consider also / alternatively http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023201/why-do-i-get-an-autolayout-error-on-a-constraint-that-should-not-be-installed-fo

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I think I am just having the same problem as mentioned in the stackoverflow above. I might consider  what is mentioned there.

Comment: I ended up removing all the landscape constraints when the device is in the portrait orientation and vice versa. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be the case but I Imagine it's a bug as per the link, as for my case 1. All works fine if I load in working orientation and then rotate to one that's not (with extra Any constraint) 2. There are no conflicts with these Any constraints in storyboard builder, suggesting that they are in fact meant to be excluded.